# Ember.js JSHint not ignoring bower_components files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, jshint

I'm building an Ember application which uses Bootstrap, and oftentimes it takes a very long time to build. I think (but am not positive) that this is because JSHint goes through my bower_components and finds errors like this:

[image]

The errors are all in bower_components/tether, bootstrap, or jquery. I have looked into excluding bower_components in .jshintrc but I haven't had any success with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broccoli used not to support `.jshintignore` but in recently they have fixed that problem . So create .jshintignore in your App root level just next to .jshintrc and then add your exclude folders.

```
node_modules/**/*
bower_components/**/*
```

Reference to follow :

1- [Support for project level .jshintignore](https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-jshint/pull/43)
2- [.jshintignore isn't being picked up](https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-jshint/issues/27)

Give it a try but if not there is another solution that you can temporary consider until that will be fixed soon.

You can ignore the file by adding

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
```

at the beginning of the file.

More info : [JShint documents](http://jshint.com/docs/)